# Am I liable for 20 year old water bill for a house I bought?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, florida

I bought a house in Florida in 2017 and when I went to get the water service turned on they told me there is a water bill from 1998 and I need to pay it. Is it my responsibility even if I didn't own the house and there had been 6 other owners before me?

Comment: How is it none of the previous 6 owners were required to pay this bill?  Did no one have water in this house for the past 19 years?

Answer (score 4):

To get an answer tailored to your problem, you need to get a lawyer. The general answer is that the water bill goes with the property, not the person using the water. The unpaid bill can become a lien on the property, and the house can be taken and sold to satisfy the lien.

There are other factors / questions. Under Florida law ([180.135](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0100-0199/0180/Sections/0180.135.html)), if the debt arises from a renter who incurred the debt directly with the utility, a lien cannot be placed against the property. Any lien must be perfected (filed with the courts), and the point of a title search is to find such liens – assuming that a title search was done. There is a limit to how long you can wait to collect on a debt (7 years).

Comment: If there's a lien, it seems to me that should be something that title insurance should cover.

Comment: Yes, except if the court is at fault (that is, the court clerk messed up and failed to register something).